# "docker push" requires exactly 1 argument in gitlabci with windows runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a very simple gitlab ci task. Just build an image from Dockerfile and push it to gitlab docker repository:

```
- echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
- docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE . 
- docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
```

And here is my output:

```
$ echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
vb-git.example.com:8888/my/test
$ docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  131.1kB

Step 1/1 : FROM openjdk
 ---> b853c027c6f5
Successfully built b853c027c6f5
Successfully tagged my.example.com:8888/my/test:latest
$ docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
"docker push" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker push --help'.

Usage:  docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]
```

Im suspecting that this has something to do with windows shell executor not parsing the push line correctly. When i write push like following it works:

```
- docker push my.example.com:8888/my/test:latest
```

But how to do this using gitlabci variable so windows shell executor wont get confused?

Comment: do you need the quotes around "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"

Comment: or maybe $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE is a string with spaces

Comment: As @physicist says, u don't need use quotes

Comment: Tried without quotes, same result. First line in second code block echoes out the variable and it does not have any spaces.

Comment: 1. Try static named image instead of variable if issue still persist then issue is with the variable value. 
2. Print variable value
3. What about login? Have you logged in?

Comment: Is there anything else other than these 3 lines? White space or new lines after the push command?

Comment: Change `docker push ...` to `echo docker push ... x` and show the output.

Comment: Try tagging and then pushing separately once , So that we can try to drill down a little more , docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $DOCKER_REPO:$SOURCE_COMMIT
docker push $DOCKER_REPO:$SOURCE_COMMIT

Comment: Expand variables and print command before execution - it depends on used shell, but for bash, you can set it with `set -x`. Then you can debug it more.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
    `docker push "${$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest"`

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```
docker push "$($CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE):latest"
```

In powershell, you use the `:` to get the property of a variable. For example, you get the environment variable path like this:

```
$Env:Path
```

If you don't want to get the property, you can evaluate the variable manually first by putting it inside a `$( )` block.

Comment: You helped me realize I was incorrectly leaving a space after the : which was giving me the error.